# Passing Values From Parent Page To User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Hi i have a `usercontrol` embedded in **multiple pages** and i want to capture that from where that the `usercontrol` is loaded (from which parent page)

how to do this ? ,

Comment: you got the info ?? is it working for you

Answer (score 1):

Expose the thing as public Property  than you able to access those in your child ones thats better way to do it

search your child control form the parent like : `parent.FindControl("Controlname")` will do it

Comment: you mean to create a public property in Usercontrol and access it ? , how to access it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your control, you can call CurrentExecutionFilePath which will provide you the path and page currently executing.  If you're only interested in the filename, simply strip off the first part looking for LastIndexOf("/").

Answer (score 0):

From the control, you can call `Page.ToString()` which should return something like `'ASP.TestPage_aspx'`